# Show images that are outside project folder jsf glassfish

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, glassfish

I want to show some images to users, which  are located here:

```
C:\Users\advert_images
```

I am using primefaces and showing using servelet:

```
   @WebServlet("/advert_images/*")
public class ImagesServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected
            void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String filename = request.getPathInfo().substring(1);
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\advert_images\\", filename);
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", getServletContext().getMimeType(filename));
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
        Files.copy(file.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
    }
```

}

So when I type in browser this:

```
http://localhost:8080/vas-plus/advert_images/3.jpg
```

I get my image.

But  when I try to write in my xhtml

```
 <img src ="http://localhost:8080/vas-plus/advert_images/3.jpg"/>
```

Or:

```
 <h:graphicImage class="test" value="/advert_images/3.jpg"/>
```

I have no image displayed. And also something this as html output:

```
<img src="/vas-plus/advert_images/3.jpg" class="test" width="0" height="0" style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 1px 1px;">
```

When I use Google Chrome developerTools to see resources of html page I see this:
[image]

So I am a little confused any Ideas?

Comment: Why you don't want to put it into your project as it should be?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like wrong Content Type header, maybe because your file are not accessible to ServletContext(not sure about that).

Try this:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String filename = request.getPathInfo().substring(1);
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\advert_images\\", filename);
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int count = 0;
    while ((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, count);
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
}
```

And I would highly recommend you to put file into your project.